# Can't make in In app purchase with Phonegap

Tags: cordova

I am trying to make an IN APP purchase in IOS. I am using phonegap cordova 2.6. I am having no response at all when I try to use the in app purchase manager linked below. I have set up all the files. The store kit. I have set up everything on Itunes Connect. The latest post on this was from 1-2 years ago. Phonegap has changed a bit since then. There is no info.plist and everything is set up in config.xml. I tried setting plug in permission through there but nothing has worked. I have went through multiple in app questions on this site.  There is nothing helpful for the more recent versions of Phonegap, and the apple developer center notes are as useful as a quadriplegic hamster. Can anyone help?

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/InAppPurchaseManager

Comment: hi..charles, have you done this?